# HTML Target links on left fixed menu not working

Tags: html

On http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html when you scroll down little bit and then click one of the (position:fixed) left menu, it doesnt jump to the top, but instead it stays where it is. I need it to jump to the top of content above the table of players after the link is clicked.

LEFT MENU

```
<div class="list-1">
    <ul>
        <li class="pokerplayers"><a href="#pokerplayers">EDPS Poker Players </a></li>
        <li class="playerofthemonth"><a href="#playerofthemonth">Players of the Month</a></li>
        <li class="playeroftheyear"><a href="#playeroftheyear">Players of the Year </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

TOP CONTENT

```
<div class="content-header"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: whats does that mean?

Comment: It means that when I follow the steps to reproduce the problem you describe, I do not encounter the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
<li class="pokerplayers">
  <a href="pokerplayers" onClick="window.scrollTo(0,0);">EDPS Poker Players </a>
</li>
```

?

Comment: I dont know why you received a negative point, but it worked for me - thanks!